# Discord bot randomly stops and starts | Process falling asleep?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, rate-limiting, replit

So i made a discord bot & hosted on replit. I set up a pinger, bot is alive, it works, everything is fine.

**But what is the problem then?**

Well, 
[image: looky at this..]

This means that the bot is online, is up for pings, AND has logged in, but is not responding to messages.

After i use `kill 1`, my bot runs fine. Maybe my bot is being rate limited??

So i made a `.sh` file. It has this code

```bash
while true; do
node .
done
```

and here's my `.replit`

```
entrypoint = "index.js"
run="bash restart.sh"
### stuff after this not important
```

Yeah, it works. Everytime my bot is being rate limited, i use `process.exit()` to restart, and my bot really did work for **3 days**.

But then back to before. Bot online, logged in, not responding. Again I have to use `kill 1` to restart

Is there anything im missing? or is this some problem with replit's or discord's servers? **Can I do anything to fix it, or at least automate it?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just replit trying to make you pay for their always on services therefore limiting stuff like this.

Comment: See [more info about Replit being rate limited](https://ask.replit.com/t/discord-ratelimit/3522?u=not-ethan)

Comment: @ethan, I got the `restart.sh` idea from there, so this isn't helpful. Could you help me solve my problem please?